# PHP doesn't use the updated OpenSSL on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, symfony, openssl

I'm trying to install composer.phar for a symfony session, but when I do so I have a warning message telling me that I need to update my openssl from 0.9.8 to 1.0.1 or above.

I did it, and I end up with

`openssl version` returning `OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016`

and

`which openssl` returning `/usr/local/bin/openssl`

However I still have the same warning message.

It looks like php still using the `/usr/bin/openssl` instead of `/usr/local/bin/openssl`

Any clue on how to make php use the `/usr/local/bin/openssl` instead of `/usr/bin/openssl`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Also see [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830) on the Apple Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compile PHP with the "--with-openssl[=DIR]" option by pointing to desired directory.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I don't believe OpenSSL uses [`install_name_tool`](https://discussions.apple.com/community/search.jspa?peopleEnabled=true&userID=&containerType=&container=&spotlight=false&q=install_name_tool), so he will need to do more than `--with-openssl[=DIR]`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you answer. What you mean by compile php?

Comment: @jww He is having the updated openssl at `/usr/local/bin/openssl`. IMO he has to compile php `--with-openssl[=DIR]` by pointing to new path. Thoughts?